# How to get WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper working in Jython 2.7b3

Tags: neo4j, jython

I have an embedded neo4j database (2.1.3) that I am using with Jython 2.7b3. I would like to be able to use the web admin provided by WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper.

My current code is:

```
from org.neo4j.server import WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper
from org.neo4j.server.configuration import ServerConfigurator
from org.neo4j.graphdb.factory import GraphDatabaseFactory
graphDb = GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase('data/')
config = ServerConfigurator(graphDb)
WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper(graphDb, config).start()
```

However when I try to start WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper I get a very long stack trace which ends on:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.JmxService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig.convertToSet(ClassNamesResourceConfig.java:118) ~[na:na]
... 51 common frames omitted

01:25:32.485 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@53f6812e: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-1365105063@3cbbb0ac==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-1365105063@3cbbb0ac==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:563) ~[na:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:351) ~[na:na]
```

Thankful for any ideas on what I missing?

Answer (score 0):

WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper is deprecated, according to [this link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper.java). You won't find a word about NeoServerBootstrapper in recent manuals...

the solution should be writing [extensions or plugins](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-extending.html) for neoserver.

Comment: Could you give an example on how this could be accomplished using an extension or plugin?

Comment: |||v||| so sorry that I haven't take a clear look of that question. My explanation is alright but solution must be totally wrong T_T...won't web admin at port 7474 provided by neo4j meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include these dependencies if you haven't already -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <classifier>static-web</classifier>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```